# How to add text to the input box by clicking on the event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Specifically, I want to add popular keywords to the search, where users can add text to the search box by clicking on the keywords. Here is an example.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#searchHot li').click(function() {
    var name = $('#searchHot li').val();
    $('#searchInput input').text(name);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div id="searchInput">
    <input type="search">
  </div>
  <ul id="searchHot">
    <span>Popular:</span>
    <li>AAA</li>
    <li>BBB</li>
    <li>CCC</li>
    <li>DDD</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

It's not working as expected, sorry I'm a jquery newbie and I'm not sure what it's getting wrong.

Any help, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few issues with the current implementation:

1. The click handler is trying to get the text of `#searchHot li`, but you want the text of the clicked list item, not all of them. You could get a reference to the clicked item with `$(e.target)`, with `e` being the event passed to the `click` function handler.
2. When getting the text of the list item, you are using `.val()` but it's not an input and you likely just want the text content, which can be done with `.text()`.
3. When setting the value of the input, you are using `.text(name)` but you want to set the input value to be the content, which can be done with `.val(name)`.

The follow code snippet should show a version where clicking on the list item will replace the contents of the input field.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#searchHot li').click(function(e) {
    var name = $(e.target).text();
    $('#searchInput input').val(name);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div id="searchInput">
    <input type="search">
  </div>
  <ul id="searchHot">
    <span>Popular:</span>
    <li>AAA</li>
    <li>BBB</li>
    <li>CCC</li>
    <li>DDD</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

If you don't want the input to be replaced and instead appended to, that could be done with something like this instead:

```js
var input = $('#searchInput input');
input.val(input.val() + ' ' + name);
```

Comment: Thanks! It is simple and easy to understand.